# Django ListVIew redirect if model has no records

Tags: django, django-models

I have built a class **PlayerListView** which uses class ListView for generic display of views.

```
class PlayerListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = PlayerSeason
    template_name = 'squad/players_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'players'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['test'] = 'test'
        context['season_name'] = PlayerSeason.objects.first().season.season_name
        return context
```

Normally if there are no records for the PlayerSeason model, the template display html code with zero data to display. But as my template also needs additional data, I needed to put it in 'context' using get_context_data().

```
context['season_name'] = PlayerSeason.objects.first().season.season_name
```

The problem occurs when there are no records for PlayerSeason and I want to set the context data for season_name. It checks for the fields in the relation  field 'season'. Because it does not exist, it returns error: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute** (logical).

What I want to avoid any errors is to redirect to the url for insertion of PlayerSeason records (lets say: '/create/playerseason'.

One of the solutions I tried was checking that in the get() method

```
    if PlayerSeason.objects.count():
        season_name = PlayerSeason.objects.first().season.season_name
    else:
        return redirect('blog-home')
```

What is the correct/elegant solution in this case?

Comment: Would it be a correct solution using a middleware ?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is okay before you add `session_name` to context check if there is any PlayerSession object in database, if so assign `context["session_name"]` to your first object's name. If there is no objects in database just simply skip assigning `session_name` In your template you can also make a checker if `session_name` exists.

```
{% if session_name %}
...
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
```